# Tense that I need to use to reply to someone on a request?

Tags: grammar

Say there is a technical ticket for me, and the user is asking "Please reset the password for xyz account..."
after I reset the password should I reply

"Your VPN password is reset."
or

"Your VPN password has been reset"

simple tense use to telegraph about a fact so if I am not wrong the first sentence means
there is this fact that I am sharing that your account password is reset. by who we didn't mention, when? we don't know, but we know it's reset, so you are good to go. is that silly or odd type of responding to this?

the present perfect however says, your vpn password was reset at some random time in the past and it's still in that state..

Comment: Your VPN password is reset works just fine. Also, Your VPN password is now reset.

Comment: Personally, I’d always write ***”has been***”.

Comment: @jim So would I, a reset is an istantaneous action which results in the password being 'available', 'usable' or otherwise returned to the state it was in before it needed resetting. You can say that it "has been" reset but, for me, "is reset" doesn't make a lot of sense.